# Google Sheets Apps Script to ascertain who are the admins in a Telegram group

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, telegram-bot

I am developing a Telegram bot and need to ascertain who are the admins in a group

Have developed a Google Web App using JavaScript and calling the following method
getChatAdministrators
Use this method to get a list of administrators in a chat. On success, returns an Array of ChatMember objects that contains information about all chat administrators

this method is returning the following:
[20-03-14 17:14:23:403 AEDT]

```
{"ok":true,
 "result":
[{"user":{"id":810784352,"is_bot":false,"first_name":"Rafael","last_name":"Vasconcelos"},"status":"administrator","can_be_edited":false,"can_change_info":true,"can_delete_messages":true,"can_invite_users":true,"can_restrict_members":true,"can_pin_messages":true,"can_promote_members":false},
 {"user":{"id":1021450393,"is_bot":false,"first_name":"Mauro","last_name":"Ramires"},"status":"administrator","can_be_edited":false,"can_change_info":true,"can_delete_messages":true,"can_invite_users":true,"can_restrict_members":true,"can_pin_messages":true,"can_promote_members":false},
 {"user":{"id":998081853,"is_bot":false,"first_name":"Filipe","last_name":"Lima"},"status":"administrator","can_be_edited":false,"can_change_info":true,"can_delete_messages":true,"can_invite_users":true,"can_restrict_members":true,"can_pin_messages":true,"can_promote_members":false},
 {"user":{"id":962548471,"is_bot":false,"first_name":"Trajano","last_name":"Roberto","username":"TrajanoRoberto","language_code":"en"},"status":"creator"},
 {"user":{"id":307271095,"is_bot":false,"first_name":"Leandro","last_name":"Silva","username":"Leandro_CRF"},"status":"administrator","can_be_edited":false,"can_change_info":true,"can_delete_messages":true,"can_invite_users":true,"can_restrict_members":true,"can_pin_messages":true,"can_promote_members":false}
]
}
```

question:
I am struggling to find correct JavaScript syntax to read:
id, first_name & last_name
for the response returned by the method
getChatAdministrators

thanks in advance for any help.

Trajano Roberto

Comment: What do you want to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are getting a JSON response from the request and it's an object. So for getting `id`, `first_name`, `last_name` you have to inspect the `response`.

Assume your request response is-

```
let response = {"ok":true, "result": [{"user":{"id":810784352,"is_bot":false,"first_name":"Rafael","last_name":"Vasconcelos"},"status":"administrator","can_be_edited":false,"can_change_info":true,"can_delete_messages":true,"can_invite_users":true,"can_restrict_members":true,"can_pin_messages":true,"can_promote_members":false}, {"user":{"id":1021450393,"is_bot":false,"first_name":"Mauro","last_name":"Ramires"},"status":"administrator","can_be_edited":false,"can_change_info":true,"can_delete_messages":true,"can_invite_users":true,"can_restrict_members":true,"can_pin_messages":true,"can_promote_members":false}, {"user":{"id":998081853,"is_bot":false,"first_name":"Filipe","last_name":"Lima"},"status":"administrator","can_be_edited":false,"can_change_info":true,"can_delete_messages":true,"can_invite_users":true,"can_restrict_members":true,"can_pin_messages":true,"can_promote_members":false}, {"user":{"id":962548471,"is_bot":false,"first_name":"Trajano","last_name":"Roberto","username":"TrajanoRoberto","language_code":"en"},"status":"creator"}, {"user":{"id":307271095,"is_bot":false,"first_name":"Leandro","last_name":"Silva","username":"Leandro_CRF"},"status":"administrator","can_be_edited":false,"can_change_info":true,"can_delete_messages":true,"can_invite_users":true,"can_restrict_members":true,"can_pin_messages":true,"can_promote_members":false}]};
```

I don't know but if it's a JSON string then parse it so that the program not fails.

```
if (typeof response === 'string') {
    response = JSON.parse(response);
}
```

Here I check if the response is a string then parse the string as JSON.

Finally, I have to iterate through the response as the required information is stored inside the `result` array's `user` object.

```
response.result.map(result => {
    console.log(result.user.id, result.user.first_name, result.user.last_name);
});
```

I just console the values. You can do whatever you want.

```js
let response = {"ok":true, "result": [{"user":{"id":810784352,"is_bot":false,"first_name":"Rafael","last_name":"Vasconcelos"},"status":"administrator","can_be_edited":false,"can_change_info":true,"can_delete_messages":true,"can_invite_users":true,"can_restrict_members":true,"can_pin_messages":true,"can_promote_members":false}, {"user":{"id":1021450393,"is_bot":false,"first_name":"Mauro","last_name":"Ramires"},"status":"administrator","can_be_edited":false,"can_change_info":true,"can_delete_messages":true,"can_invite_users":true,"can_restrict_members":true,"can_pin_messages":true,"can_promote_members":false}, {"user":{"id":998081853,"is_bot":false,"first_name":"Filipe","last_name":"Lima"},"status":"administrator","can_be_edited":false,"can_change_info":true,"can_delete_messages":true,"can_invite_users":true,"can_restrict_members":true,"can_pin_messages":true,"can_promote_members":false}, {"user":{"id":962548471,"is_bot":false,"first_name":"Trajano","last_name":"Roberto","username":"TrajanoRoberto","language_code":"en"},"status":"creator"}, {"user":{"id":307271095,"is_bot":false,"first_name":"Leandro","last_name":"Silva","username":"Leandro_CRF"},"status":"administrator","can_be_edited":false,"can_change_info":true,"can_delete_messages":true,"can_invite_users":true,"can_restrict_members":true,"can_pin_messages":true,"can_promote_members":false}]};

if (typeof response === 'string') {
 response = JSON.parse(response);
}

response.result.map(result => {
 console.log(`id: ${result.user.id}`, `first_name: ${result.user.first_name}`, `last_name: ${result.user.last_name}`);
});
```

Comment: hey Sajeeb

sadly, this statement is incorrect, since
    if (typeof response === 'string') {
        response = JSON.parse(response);
}

  var aChatMember = getChatAdministrators( chat_id );

returns object and not string

anyway, thanks for the help

Comment: Actually I don't know that it returns a string or object. It's a security check, If the response is a string then parse it. If you are sure that it's an object then skip this parse.

Comment: thanks for the response
for clarity, it is better to be sure what to post, else it might confuse

setWebhook

Use this method to specify a url and receive incoming updates via an outgoing webhook. Whenever there is an update for the bot, we will send an HTTPS POST request to the specified url, containing a JSON-serialized Update. In case of an unsuccessful request, we will give up after a reasonable amount of attempts. Returns True on success.

Update

This object represents an incoming update.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the above output object is in the variable `obj`, you could use the following snippet to log the details of each user:

```
 var results = obj.result;  
  if (results.length > 0) {
    for (var r in results) {
      var user = results[r].user;
      Logger.log([user.id, user.first_name, user.last_name])
    }
  }
```

To understand this, if you parse the object (in a [tool like this](https://jsonparseronline.com/)), all the users are in an array in `result`. And each user's details are in `user`.

Answer (score 1):

You can find `id`, `first_name` & `last_name` with help of `map()` function something like below snippet.

```js
var myArray = {"ok":true,"result":[{"user":{"id":810784352,"is_bot":false,"first_name":"Rafael","last_name":"Vasconcelos"},"status":"administrator","can_be_edited":false,"can_change_info":true,"can_delete_messages":true,"can_invite_users":true,"can_restrict_members":true,"can_pin_messages":true,"can_promote_members":false},{"user":{"id":1021450393,"is_bot":false,"first_name":"Mauro","last_name":"Ramires"},"status":"administrator","can_be_edited":false,"can_change_info":true,"can_delete_messages":true,"can_invite_users":true,"can_restrict_members":true,"can_pin_messages":true,"can_promote_members":false},{"user":{"id":998081853,"is_bot":false,"first_name":"Filipe","last_name":"Lima"},"status":"administrator","can_be_edited":false,"can_change_info":true,"can_delete_messages":true,"can_invite_users":true,"can_restrict_members":true,"can_pin_messages":true,"can_promote_members":false},{"user":{"id":962548471,"is_bot":false,"first_name":"Trajano","last_name":"Roberto","username":"TrajanoRoberto","language_code":"en"},"status":"creator"},{"user":{"id":307271095,"is_bot":false,"first_name":"Leandro","last_name":"Silva","username":"Leandro_CRF"},"status":"administrator","can_be_edited":false,"can_change_info":true,"can_delete_messages":true,"can_invite_users":true,"can_restrict_members":true,"can_pin_messages":true,"can_promote_members":false}]}

JSON.parse(JSON.stringify([myArray])).map(function(v,i) {
  v.result.map(function(v2, i2){
    console.log('ID:'+v2.user.id+' ==> First Name:'+v2.user.first_name+' ==> Last Name:'+v2.user.last_name)
  })
})
```